# Derived class not recognized as covariant

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, covariance

So I am creating a Huffman tree, and I am having a hard time overriding a function, and I believe that it is due to a covariance issue. Here is the hierarchy that I am having a hard time with in my code:

```
class TreeInterface {
public:

    TreeInterface() {}
    virtual ~TreeInterface() {}

    virtual NodeInterface * getRootNode() const = 0;
};

class Tree : TreeInterface
{
public:
    Tree() 
    {}
    virtual ~Tree() 
    {}

    Node* getRootNode()
    {
        return treeRoot;
    }

    private:
    Node* treeRoot;
};
```

Those work just fine, but its the next block that has issues.

```
class HuffmanInterface{
public:
    HuffmanInterface() {}
    virtual ~HuffmanInterface() {}

    virtual bool createTree(string filename) = 0;

    virtual string encodeMessage(string toEncode) = 0;

    virtual TreeInterface * getTree() = 0;

    virtual map<char, string> getEncodings() = 0;
};
class Huffman : HuffmanInterface{
public:

    Huffman() {}
    ~Huffman() {}

bool Huffman::createTree(string filename){ }

string Huffman::encodeMessage(string toEncode){ }

string Huffman::decodeMessage(string toDecode){ }

Tree* Huffman::getTree(){ }

map<char, string> Huffman::getEncodings(){ }
```

So the problem is apparently in the getTree() function, giving the following error

```
invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual Tree* Huffman::getTree()’:
Tree * getTree();
```

but as far as I know, Tree* should be a valid covariant of TreeInterface*. replacing Tree* with TreeInterface* makes the program compile, but it's not what I need in my actual program. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Tree : TreeInterface { ... };
```

is equivalent to

```
class Tree : private TreeInterface { ... };
```

You need to make the inheritance `public`.

```
class Tree : public TreeInterface { ... };
```

Comment: Oh man, I knew it was a small, stupid thing like like that haha. Thanks man, that was very helpful!

Comment: @TaylorBradshaw, rest assured that that won't be last stupid mistake you will make :) :)